# how to use exp in Symbolic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

how can i use exp in Symbolic regression (gplearn)?

i tried "make_function" with np.exp, but it immediately gets overflowed.[results of a run with exp function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xddm2.png)

in general im trying to recover this formula
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eexUD.jpg)

input: float

Comment: what's the datatype of x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not answering your question. I just wanted to point out that gplearn is perhaps not the best choice for symbolic regression in Python these days. Check out the result this symbolic regression copetition from the recent gecco conference:

https://cavalab.org/srbench/competition-2022/

Several of these methods would likely deal with your exp problem out-of-the-box.